# Replace/Change element type in XSD file using java DOM

Tags: java, dom, xsd

I always gets an answer to my question from "Stackoverflow" and this is first time, I am posting my question.

I am reading XSD file using DOM in java. In my XSD, I need to change type of an element.

```
<xs:complexType name="MainDoc">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Bike" type="Vehicle"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Vehicle">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="price" type="amount"/>            
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Here, I want to change type="Vehicle" to type="Twowheeler" when element name is "bike" and all occurrences of "vehicle" to "Twowheeler".
I read XSD using DOM component so is this possible to change this?

(Workaround to this problem will be, I will replace word "vehicle" from XSD file using file handling operations but I don't prefer this)

Please help...

Comment: is DOM a requirement or you are open to something that could be comparable, if not better?

Comment: I am open to any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code to do the attribute update with XPath and VTD-XML.

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
import java.io.*;
public class updateXSD {
    public static void main(String[] s) throws VTDException, IOException{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        if (!vg.parseFile("d:\\xml\\xsd.xml", true)){
            return;
        }
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        ap.declareXPathNameSpace("xs", "XSD namespace here");
        ap.selectXPath("//xs:element[@name='Bike']/@type");
        XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier(vn);
        int i=-1;
        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            xm.updateToken(i+1, "Twowheeler");
        }
        xm.output("d:\\xml\\newXSD.xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Though it didn't change all occurrences of Vehicle with Twowheeler. I have further modified it as per my requirement.